# How can I force Ruby numbers to behave like integers, not fixnums?

Tags: ruby, math, integer, fixnum

I have:

```
steven$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > foo = "256MB"
 => "256MB" 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > interim_result = foo.slice(/\d+/).to_i
 => 256 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > interim_result.class
 => Fixnum 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > result = interim_result/1028
 => 0
```

I want `result` to be `0.25`. How can I make this happen?

Is it necessary/possible to force `interim_result.class` to be `integer`?

Please note the following doesn't give the desired result of 0.25:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > interim_result = foo.slice(/\d+/).to_f
 => 256.0 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > result = interim_result/1028
 => 0.2490272373540856 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > result.round_to(2)
NoMethodError: undefined method `round_to' for 0.2490272373540856:Float
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way would be to call `to_f` instead of `to_i` when assigning a value to `interim_result`.

Comment: No can do sorry. Just updated the question to show the result of taking that route.

Comment: It tells you there's no method `round_to` and you didn't even try to see if there's another way to round? `>> result.round(2) #=> 0.25`.

Comment: Oops, right you are. I read something too quickly. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quit sure what you mean behave like an integer. IF that was completely true you would have nothing after a decimal; however, I believe you can use `round()` to achieve what you want.

```
 ruby-1.9.2-p180-mri :001 > a = 0.2490272373540856 
 => 0.2490272373540856 
 ruby-1.9.2-p180-mri :002 > a.round(2)
 => 0.25 
 ruby-1.9.2-p180-mri :003 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a litte explanation what's going wrong in your example.

interim_result is correct 256. and the this happens:

```
256 / 1024 #-> 0
```

/ with two fixnums (integer) is kind of modula division.
To show it: you get the first value of:

```
256.divmod(1024)#-> [0, 256]
256.divmod(1024).first #-> 0
```

Some solutions (I changed your entry values. your 256 / 1028 is not 0.25, but 24.9..... See Codeglots answer):

```
256 / 1024.0 #-> 0.25
```

Perhaps Rational is another nice solution:

```
256 / Rational(1024,1) #-> (1/4)
256 * Rational(1,1024) #-> (1/4)
```